# Dynamics365 - Unable to find the corresponding element when a button clicked and a popup showsup

Tags: c#, selenium, dynamics-365

Trying to automate Dynamics365, click **Farm Tax** button and select **PPR** listed (large red box to the left). Highlighted text is the id for the button. Not able find where the listings (PPR or any other) are in Developer Tools in Chrome. Only *"are-haspopup"* is changing from *"false"* to *"true"*, when button is clicked (see small red box in the middle). How to find the elements that represent the popup (large red box)?

[image]

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: The code finds the element highlighted. Then I has no idea how to find the elements for the choices that popped up (PPR, FBR etc. in red box).

Comment: var frameId = findByElements.FindById("AppLandingPage");
            Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameId);

            findByElements.FindById("AppTileContainerSec_1_LI_1").Click();
            findByElements.FindById("areaSwitcherId").Click();

Comment: Also "area-label" (just after the highlighted text) changed after making a choice from the pop-up. I need find a way programmatically click any of the pop-up choices (PPR, FBR etc.)

Comment: Also the class is changing (above the gray highlight across) is changing for each choice.

Comment: This might take some trouble shooting.  I can message you in this channel.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium

Answer (score 0):

This may take some trouble shooting. Here is something to try. We will try to find the element of the dropdown by the text value.

```
var frameId = findByElements.FindById("AppLandingPage"); 
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameId);
findByElements.FindById("AppTileContainerSec_1_LI_1").Click();
findByElements.FindById("areaSwitcherId").Click();

Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'PPR')]")).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks Jortega. Tried it and getting " element not interactable" exception. This due to the menu pops up as a different window/frame?

Comment: @Nick That means we found the element. Do you know how to see if there is more than one element matching that xpath using `FindElements`?

Comment: Thank You and it worked. It was returning multiple occurrences and issue is resolved.